# Enable searching //TODO tags in *.module extension file

Tags: eclipse, drupal

I wanted to use // TODO tags in drupal file "*.module".

1. I've activate the searching for task tag(content types are: 
   "css,html,DTD,XML").
2. The *.module extension is associate with the drupal module extension.
3. I've check the "configure contents" of the search filtering from "Task view".
4. Tags for php comments are; Fixme, @todo, TODO(Default).

There's something missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Drupal plug-in for Eclipse IDE by XTND.US. Update site: http://xtnd.us/downloads/eclipse

With this plugin installed and working, you should see **TODO** highlighted in your code and *.module files should be opened as php. All todo should appear in *Tasks* Eclipse view.

Comment: thx @alessandro-pezzato But this link is broken!!! and i've already installed Drupal plug-in. i juste want that elipse look when seraching for TODO tags in my files "*.modules"

Comment: @lolita: The link isn't broken. It's an update-site, so you need to use the "install new software" dialog.

Comment: thx @looper but this plugin is already installed, I don't think that's the problem :/

Comment: With this plugin installed and working, you should see **TODO** highlighted in your code and .module should be opened as php. All todo should appear in *Tasks* Eclipse view.

Comment: For some raison, It was the version of the installed Dupal plugin i think . I have uninstalled it, all things become all right. thx